# Mule-ESB: Mule filter based on HTTP Status

Tags: mule, mule-studio

How do I use a filter other than a choice filter to call a subflow based on the http status?

```
<flow>  
<http:outbound-endpoint exhange-pattern="request-response>
if http.status!=201  
<flow-ref="subflow-to-invoke">  
</flow>
```

Comment: Question is: what do you want to do if the status is 201?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this post [Mule-esb: Process Jersey Response based on Status code using Choice Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781993/mule-esb-process-jersey-response-based-on-status-code-using-choice-router)

Here is snippet from the above link, that answers your question.

```
<flow> 
<http:outbound-endpoint address="${host}" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
<choice>
     <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]==201">  
         <flow-ref name=="flow2">  
     </when>
     <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']]==503">  
         <flow-ref name="flow3">
     </when>
     <when expression="#[payload instanceof java.lang.SocketException]">
         <flow-ref name="flow4">  
     </when>
     <otherwise>
     <!-- decide what you want to do here -->
     </otherwise> 
 </choice>
```

Comment: Ineed it will work, but you need to add extra '' in comparing http.status.

It should like: #[message.inboundProperties['http.status']=='201']

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a filter for that but a choice message processor:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Choice+Flow+Control+Reference