# Mule-esb: Process Jersey Response based on Status code using Choice Router?

Tags: mule

How can I process a `Jersey Rest` Service Response based on `201` or `503`? Can I mix `groovy` and other  evaluators?  In my example, part is using message properties and other groovy

```
<flow> 
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="${host}" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <when expression="message:INBOUND:http.status==201">  
    <flow-ref name=="flow2">  
    <when expression="message:INBOUND:http.status==503">  
    <flow-ref name="flow3">
    <when expression="payload instanceof java.lang.SocketException" evaluator="groovy">
    <flow-ref name="flow4">  
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this using [MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL) syntax.

`choice` needs an `otherwise` block also, decide what you want to do in that case.

```
<flow> 
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="${host}" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <choice>
         <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']==201]">  
             <flow-ref name=="flow2">  
         </when>
         <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status']==503]">  
             <flow-ref name="flow3">
         </when>
         <when expression="#[exception instanceof java.net.SocketException]">
             <flow-ref name="flow4">  
         </when>
         <otherwise>
         <!-- decide what you want to do here -->
         </otherwise> 
     </choice>
</flow>
```